# How can train YOLOV3 with Stanford Drone Dataset?

Tags: computer-vision, artificial-intelligence, object-detection, yolo

I want to train my YOLOV3 with Stanford Drone Dataset but IDK how can do it. Someone has any idea?

Stanford Drone Dataset: http://cvgl.stanford.edu/projects/uav_data/

Answer (score 0):

You can use [AlexeyAB](https://github.com/AlexeyAB/darknet#how-to-train-to-detect-your-custom-objects) repository to annotate your data accordingly. There is a tool called YOLO_mark there which you can use to draw bounding boxes around objects. In the dataset you mentioned, seems like the data is already annotated. If so, you can use matlab or any other tool to convert the annotation formats to the format of YOLO, which is relative values of each box coordinates:

`<object-class> <x_center> <y_center> <width> <height>`